# Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H|=p$, a prime. Prove that for every subgroup $K\le G$ either $H\le K$ of $H \cap K =1$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

So this is a past paper question for my group theory class and I just need to know if my logic is correct. It is supposed to be answered using Lagrange's theorem. My course only deals with finite groups. Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H|=p$, a prime. Prove that for every subgroup $K\le G$ either $H\le K$ of $H \cap K =1$.

Let $G$ have order $n$ and $K$ have order k. Then by Lagrange's theorem, $\frac{n}{p}$ and $\frac{n}{k}$, must equal integers. We call these $r$ and $s$ respectively. As now $n=rp$, $s$ must divide $rp$. If $\frac{rp}{s}=r$. Then $k=r$. As the orders of $|K|$ and $|H|$ are coprime, their intersection must only be the identity. If $s=mp$ where $m < r$, then $k=\frac{r}{m}$, which is an integer greater than one, thus $H\leq K$. Does my lockig make sense?

Kindest regards,

Catherine

Comment: Or just notice that $H\cap K$ must be a subgroup of $H$ ...

Comment: You can assume that $H$ is not a subgroup of $K$. Only this case matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L=H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

By 
Lagrange's theorem, $|L|$ divides $|H|$, which is a prime. Thus, $|L|=1$ or $|L|=|H|$.

If $|L|=1$, then $H\cap K = L = 1$.

If $|L|=|H|$, then $H\cap K = L = H$ and $H \le K$.